# How to add option at first position in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-select

I `ng-option` element in my page.

Here how it looks in template:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>
```

In controller:

```
 $scope.selectedItem = {};

 $scope.items = [{name: 'one', id: 30 },{ name: 'two', id: 27 },{ name: 'threex', id: 50 }];
```

In my project I get scope items from some lookup table.

I need to add to ng-select this element with value `-1`:

```
<option value="-1">- manual -</option>
```

And it looks like that:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id">
   <option value="-1">- manual -</option>
</select>
```

Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sMn33p2FKOywowZwGbvd?p=preview).

But I don't see in view `manual` option.

Any idea why I cant see manual option in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've object with `id-name` pair, you need to use unshift to add a new option at first position.

```
$scope.items.unshift({name: 'manual', id:-1});
```

Then specify the option to be selected by default.

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.items = [{name: 'one', id: 30 },{ name: 'two', id: 27 },{ name: 'threex', id: 50 }];
  
  $scope.items.unshift({name: 'manual', id:-1});
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id">
      
    </select>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need this value in the option

Answer (score 0):

add the option in the controller after fetching items,

```
$scope.items.push({name:'-manual-', id: -1});
```

[updated code](https://plnkr.co/edit/GUWyx3VWbgHTJvX9GiPH?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

change your select like below

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id">
   <option value="">Manual</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just put **ng-selected** ="desirable item value" attribute to select element that is it.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id" ng-selected="50">
 <option value="">Manual</option>
</select>
```